# Chunkinfying stream. Is code correct? Need a second set of eyes

Tags: c#, stream

Can anyone see any obvious holes in my logic here.  Basically I need to break up a byte array into chunks of 10,000 before sending it out:

```
byte [] bytes = GetLargePieceOfData();    
Stream stream = CreateAStream();

if (bytes.Length > 10000)
{
    int pos = 0;
    int chunkSize = 10000;

    while (pos < bytes.Length)
    {
        if (pos + chunkSize > bytes.Length)
            chunkSize = bytes.Length - pos;

        stream.Write(bytes, pos, chunkSize);
        pos += chunkSize;
    }
}
else
{
    stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything seems to be in order, but the outermost if statement is really redundant, as the following code

```
int pos = 0;
int chunkSize = 10000;

while (pos < bytes.Length)
{
    if (pos + chunkSize > bytes.Length)
        chunkSize = bytes.Length - pos;

    stream.Write(bytes, pos, chunkSize);
    pos += chunkSize;
}
```

will also handle the case where the array is smaller than the chunk size.